# Getting error while running Appium test on Android " An unknown server-side error occurred.."

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

I am Getting error "Encountered internal error running command: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Namespace with prefix 'android' has not been declared." while running appium tests on Android 8.0

I am using appium 1.15.1
Java client 7.1
JDK 1.8

I had tried changing class to RemoteWebDriver/AppiumDriver but to no avail. My code is trying to do swipe

following is the code

```
AndroidDriver<WebElement>driver=new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(url, caps);
        WebElement panel=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android:id/text1[@class='android.widget.TextView']"));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@content-desc='Graphics']")).click();
        Dimension dimension=panel.getSize();
        int anchor=panel.getSize().getHeight()/2;
        Double ScreenWidthStart = dimension.getWidth() * 0.8;
        int scrollStart = ScreenWidthStart.intValue();  

        Double ScreenWidthEnd = dimension.getWidth() * 0.2;
        int scrollEnd = ScreenWidthEnd.intValue();

        new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) driver)
                    .press(PointOption.point(scrollStart, anchor))
                    .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(1000)))
                    .moveTo(PointOption.point(scrollEnd, anchor)).release().perform();
```

Please help

Comment: It seems there is issue with Appium 1.15. When I downgraded to 1.13 I was not getting this error.

Comment: At which line did this error occur ?

Answer (score 0):

`adb devices` please check connected your device to adb host

run this command in your host `adb devices`

Comment: The device was connected. I was able to see the device id

Comment: and appium server is running?